# QCameraViewFinder Can't set parent

Tags: qt, camera

Well, finally after I've completed everything that I want to make with `QCamera`, I've set viewFinder that is working very well too. But when I set parent of `this`, my dialog becomes black, and buttons can't be touched. So, if you are wondering why do I need parent of `this`, I need it because when I close the viewFinder my whole program close. Can you tell me what should I do?

I declare `QCameraViewfinder *viewFinder` in the header file.
Then I make new object of it: `viewFinder = new QCameraFiewFinder(this);`
And finally show it through button: `viewFinder->show();`

Comment: Do you want to embed the view finder into "this", or make it a separate dialog?

Comment: I want to make it separate dialog.Cause in this gui project i 've got lot of dialogs.

Comment: Then put it into a QDialog.

Comment: Frank, actually the viewFinder is in my cameraclass.I call the cameraclass through MainWindow.In which QDialog you mean, i should put it in? My code looks like that: QCameraViewFinder *viewFinder;, then in the cpp file viewFinder = new QCameraViewFinder();  Should i write something in the brackets? with (this), not working ;(  . Thanks a lot again.